# Unexpected namespace behavior with closures

Tags: php, namespaces, closures

Using PHP 7.0, consider the code below:

```
<?php
namespace A {
    $closure = function() {
        echo __NAMESPACE__;
    };
}
namespace B {
    $closure = function () {
        echo __NAMESPACE__;
    };
}
namespace C {
    $closure();
}
```

To me, the expected output would be:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: closure
```

But somehow the result is

```
B
```

Then consider this code below:

```
<?php
namespace A {
    $closure = function() {
        echo __NAMESPACE__;
    };
}
namespace B {
    $closure = function () {
        echo __NAMESPACE__;
    };
}
namespace C {
    \A\$closure();
}
```

Now knowing (but not yet understanding) the behavior of the first example the expected output to me would be:

```
A
```

But instead I get

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$closure' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

This behavior completely confuses me.

Question part 1: can someone explain me what is wrong with my expectation in the first example?
Question part 2: how is the behavior consistent with the first example?

Comment: In a namespace you can define classes, constants and functions. Variable is not class, not function, not constant.

Comment: For your last example, I guess (but I'm not sure) that the `$closure` variable goes out of scope at the end of its namespace. But I don't know how you can get 'B' in your first example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior you observed should not confuse you.
It is what supposed to happen.
It is exactly how PHP namespace works.

[PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) explains:

> PHP Namespaces provide a way in which to group related classes, interfaces, functions and constants.

Not variables.

This means that `$closure` in your code is the exact same variable in all the namespaces you defined (A, B and C).
It is first defined in namespace A.
Then the value is replaced in namespace B.
Then you call the closure it contains in namespace C.

The second example is the same.
Because namespaces are not for grouping variables, it should be obvious that `\A\$closure()` is an invalid syntax.